# Problema com fscanf

Tags: c, array, arquivo, estrutura-de-dados

Boa noite!
Estou com uma dúvida no meu segundo `fscanf` da parte dos PACIENTES, porque queria guardar a data que aparece no ficheiro de texto (o dia em a->h.d_dia, o mes em a->h.d_mes e o ano em a->h.d_ano), mas está-me a aparecer números aleatórios na consola.
Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

P.S: Na parte dos médicos também era suposto aparecer alguma coisa, mas não consigo achar o erro. Se alguém souber, também agradeço.

```
struct hora_entrada{int horas, minutos;};

struct hora_saida{int horas, minutos;};

typedef struct medico med, *p_med;
struct medico{
    char nome[ST_TAM];
    char especialidade[ST_TAM];
    struct hora_entrada h_e;
    struct hora_saida h_s;
    p_med prox;
};

struct data_nasc{int dia, mes, ano;};

struct historico{
    char grau[ST_TAM];
    int d_dia;
    int d_mes;
    int d_ano;
    char nome[ST_TAM];
};

typedef struct paciente pac, *p_pac;
struct paciente{
    char nome[ST_TAM];
    struct data_nasc d_n;
    int consultas;
    struct historico h;
    p_pac prox;
    };


int le_dados (){
FILE *f, *g;
med *v;
pac *a;
int i;
f=fopen("medico.txt", "rt");
g=fopen("paciente.txt", "rt");
if (f==NULL || g==NULL){
    printf("Erro no acesso ao ficheiro.\n");
    return 0;
}
v=malloc(sizeof(med));
a=malloc(sizeof(pac));
if (v==NULL || a==NULL){
    printf("Erro na alocaçao de memoria.\n");
    return 0;
}

printf("\nMEDICOS\n");
while (fscanf(f,"%49[^\n] %49s %d:%d-%d:%d",v->nome, v->especialidade, &v->h_e.horas, &v->h_e.minutos, &v->h_s.horas, &v->h_s.minutos )==6 )
        printf("%s %s %d %d %d %d\n",v->nome, v->especialidade, &v->h_e.horas, &v->h_e.minutos, &v->h_s.horas, &v->h_s.minutos);

printf("\n\nPACIENTES\n");
while (fscanf(g,"%49[^\n] %d-%d-%d %d",a->nome, &a->d_n.dia, &a->d_n.mes, &a->d_n.ano, &a->consultas)==5)
        printf("Nome: %s\nData de nascimento: %d-%d-%d\nConsultas: %d\n",a->nome, a->d_n.dia, a->d_n.mes, a->d_n.ano, a->consultas);
        for(i=0;i<a->consultas;i++){
            fscanf(g,"%s %d %d %d",a->h.grau, &a->h.d_dia, &a->h.d_mes, &a->h.d_ano);
            printf("\t%s %d/%d/%d",a->h.grau, a->h.d_dia, a->h.d_mes, a->h.d_ano);
        }
fclose(f);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

A leitura que está a ser feita no ficheiro de pacientes não corresponde à forma com os dados estão dispostos no mesmo.

Para além disso o `for` não está dentro do `while` pois faltam as `{` apesar de visualmente enganar pela identação.

Então isto:

```
printf("\n\nPACIENTES\n");
while (fscanf(g,"%49[^\n] %d-%d-%d %d",a->nome, &a->d_n.dia, &a->d_n.mes, &a->d_n.ano, &a->consultas)==5)
    printf("Nome: %s\nData de nascimento: %d-%d-%d\nConsultas: %d\n",a->nome, a->d_n.dia, a->d_n.mes, a->d_n.ano, a->consultas);
    for(i=0;i<a->consultas;i++){
        fscanf(g,"%s %d %d %d",a->h.grau, &a->h.d_dia, &a->h.d_mes, &a->h.d_ano);
        printf("\t%s %d/%d/%d",a->h.grau, a->h.d_dia, a->h.d_mes, a->h.d_ano);
    }
```

Para estar corretamente identado deveria estar assim:

```
printf("\n\nPACIENTES\n");
while (fscanf(g,"%49[^\n] %d-%d-%d %d",a->nome, &a->d_n.dia, &a->d_n.mes, &a->d_n.ano, &a->consultas)==5)
    printf("Nome: %s\nData de nascimento: %d-%d-%d\nConsultas: %d\n",a->nome, a->d_n.dia, a->d_n.mes, a->d_n.ano, a->consultas);

for(i=0;i<a->consultas;i++){
    fscanf(g,"%s %d %d %d",a->h.grau, &a->h.d_dia, &a->h.d_mes, &a->h.d_ano);
    printf("\t%s %d/%d/%d",a->h.grau, a->h.d_dia, a->h.d_mes, a->h.d_ano);
}
```

Para corrigir as chavetas e os `fscanf`s deve então ficar assim:

```
printf("\n\nPACIENTES\n");
while (fscanf(g,"%49[^\n] %d-%d-%d %d",a->nome, &a->d_n.dia, &a->d_n.mes, &a->d_n.ano, &a->consultas)==5) {
    printf("Nome: %s\nData de nascimento: %d-%d-%d\nConsultas: %d\n",a->nome, a->d_n.dia, a->d_n.mes, a->d_n.ano, a->consultas);

    for(i=0; i<a->consultas; i++)
    {
        //este fscanf ficou agora como %s - %d/%d/%d - %*[^\n]\n
        fscanf(g,"%s - %d/%d/%d - %*[^\n]\n",a->h.grau, &a->h.d_dia, &a->h.d_mes, &a->h.d_ano);
        printf("\t%s %d/%d/%d",a->h.grau, a->h.d_dia, a->h.d_mes, a->h.d_ano);
    }
}
```

Apesar de já passar pelos dados corretos cada linha de histórico, no `for` o `h` está a ser sobrepor a linha lida anteriormente, e o mesmo para o `a` que refere o paciente e sobrepõe o paciente anterior.

Será por isso necessário criar estruturas, tais como listas ou arrays, que armazenem as várias linhas de histórico e pacientes, nos locais corretos.

**Edit (referente ao armazenar dos elementos dinamicamente)**

Para guardar os elementos, que vem no ficheiro precisa de arrays ou listas, e curiosamente as suas estruturas de `paciente` e `medico` já são listas!

Se olharmos atentamente:

```
struct paciente
{
    ...
    p_pac prox; //typedef struct paciente pac, *p_pac;
};
```

Em que `p_pac` é basicamente `paciente*` ou seja um ponteiro para o próximo `paciente`. E o mesmo acontece na estrutura `medico`:

```
struct medico
{
    ...
    p_med prox;  //typedef struct medico med, *p_med;
};
```

Podemos começar por criar duas funções para mostrar cada uma das listas seguindo o estilo de amostragem que estava a utilizar:

```
void imprimirMedicos(med *lista){
    while (lista != NULL){
        printf("%s %s %d %d %d %d\n",lista->nome, lista->especialidade, lista->h_e.horas,
               lista->h_e.minutos, lista->h_s.horas, lista->h_s.minutos);

        lista = lista->prox;
    }
}

void imprimirPacientes(pac *lista){
    while (lista != NULL){
        printf("\nNome: %s\nData de nascimento: %d-%d-%d\nConsultas: %d\n",lista->nome, lista->d_n.dia, lista->d_n.mes,
               lista->d_n.ano, lista->consultas);
        lista = lista->prox;
    }
}
```

Com algumas correções pois tinha `printf`s utilizando o endereço da variável (`&`) que não é suposto, por exemplo aqui:

```
while (fscanf(f, ...) == 6 )
    printf("%s %s %d %d %d %d\n" ..., &v->h_e.horas, &v->h_e.minutos, ...);
```

Agora cada vez que se lê pode-se ir construindo a lista para a frente. Tentei utilizar uma forma simples de construir a lista que implique não alterar muito o que tem e por isso não quer dizer seja a melhor implementação. Mas seria algo como:

```
int le_dados ()
{
    FILE *f, *g;

    med *v = malloc (sizeof(med));
    pac *a = malloc (sizeof(pac));

    ... //abertura dos ficheiros e ifs que estavam aqui antes

    printf("\nMEDICOS\n");
    med *listaMedicos = v; //dizer que a lista começa no v, o primeiro médico
    med *anterior = NULL; 

    while (fscanf(f,"%49[^\n] %49s %d.%d - %d.%d\n",v->nome, v->especialidade, &v->h_e.horas, &v->h_e.minutos, &v->h_s.horas, &v->h_s.minutos )==6 ){
        v->prox = malloc (sizeof(med)); //alocar um Nó para o próximo médico
        anterior = v; //ponteiro para o médico antes do fim
        v = v->prox;
    }

    if (anterior == NULL){ //não deu para ler nenhum médico libertar o único nó alocado
        free(listaMedicos);
        listaMedicos = NULL;//por a único apontar para NULL a impressão funcionar 
    }
    else {
        free(anterior->prox);//libertar o ultimo médico alocado que não foi utilizado
        anterior->prox = NULL;//por a ultimo apontar para NULL a impressão funcionar 
    }

    imprimirMedicos(listaMedicos);


    pac *listaPacientes = a; //dizer que a lista começa no a, o primeiro paciente
    pac *antPac = NULL;

    printf("\n\nPACIENTES\n");
    while (fscanf(g,"%49[^\n] %d-%d-%d %d",a->nome, &a->d_n.dia, &a->d_n.mes, &a->d_n.ano, &a->consultas)==5) {

        for(i=0; i<a->consultas; i++)
        {
            //agora com * para ignorar e ler sem colocar em lado nenhum
            fscanf(g,"%*s - %*d/%*d/%*d - %*[^\n]\n");
        }

        a->prox = malloc(sizeof(pac)); //alocar um Nó para o próximo paciente
        antPac = a; //ponteiro para o antes do fim
        a = a->prox;
    }

    if (antPac == NULL){//não deu para ler nenhum paciente, libertar o único nó alocado
        free(listaPacientes);
        listaPacientes = NULL;//por a único apontar para NULL a impressão funcionar 
    }
    else {
        free(antPac->prox); //libertar o ultimo paciente alocado que não foi utilizado
        antPac->prox = NULL;//por a ultimo apontar para NULL a impressão funcionar 
    }

    imprimirPacientes(listaPacientes);
}
```

Deixa propositadamente por implementar a parte do histórico para poder exercitar as suas técnicas de programação. Relembro no entanto que a estrutura do histórico não está ainda preparada para funcionar como uma lista.

Comment: Muito obrigada, já está a funcionar!
Neste momento só está a aparecer a informação relativamente a um paciente, tenho de fazer um for para mostrar todos do ficheiro?

Comment: @JoanaSantos já coloquei um `\n` que estava em falta. Da forma que está já passa por toda a informação do ficheiro. Falta no entanto armazenar cada num sitio diferente.

Comment: Peço desculpa... mas sabes como posso fazer isso?
Sou uma iniciante em C...

Comment: @JoanaSantos Editei a minha resposta para contemplar o armazenamento da informação

Comment: Muito obrigada!